# How to use if statement within Select case argument

Tags: excel, vba

I need to use a select statement but at the same time for one of the case statements I need to use if statement within it because there are multiple cases for it and the same action, will be performed on all those items. I am unable to figure it out. Basically I need to perform the same action if any item present within array contains 'API' as text.

I have an array strARR which has multiple values.

```
Select Case (strARR)
 Case "UI"
    msgbox "I am UI"
Case "DB"
   msgbox "I am DB"
Case (if (instr(strARR,"API")>0))     'This is where I am getting issue
  msgbox "I am one of the API"
Case Else
  msgbox "I am nothing"
End Select
```

Comment: Could you have `case "API"` and then an If within that? If not, you'll have to turn it round to `select case true` and `case instr(strARR,"API")>0)`.

Comment: "I have an array strARR which has multiple values." - in which case that code won't work at all.

Comment: @SJR: I can't use case "API" because values which I am targetting are API_webservice1, API_webservice2, etc. So that's why I want to use instring. But I can't use select case true either because I have certain values like UI, DB which I will have to use as it is or I have to use similar boolean logic for all of the items, it seems.

Comment: You are looking at an **array**, not a string. You can't compare an array with a string literal (or anything really)... what are you trying to achieve exactly? Determine whether the array **contains** a given string element? Determine whether *an element* in the array contains a particular string? In any case, you can't work with the array itself directly, you need to iterate the array to work with its individual elements. i.e. "this is where I am getting issue" is actually on `Select Case (strARR)`, because `(strARR)` can't be legally evaluated.

Comment: Convert the array to a string, like `sample = "|" & Join(strARR, "|") & "|"`, then check `Select Case True` and `Case InStr(sample, "|API_") > 0`, where `|` in this case is equivalent to item boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strARR` being an array, you can't treat it as if it were any one of its elements: an array is an array, not a string; you can't compare an array of strings to another string, nor can you use string functions like `InStr` to determine whether the array contains a value.

Use a `For...Next` loop to iterate the array, using `LBound` and `UBound` to get the lower and upper boundaries of the array (never hard-code those!), and then use array subscripts to retrieve the element at the current index:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(strARR) To UBound(strARR)

    Dim element As String
    element = strARR(i)

    MsgBox ProcessElement(element)

Next
```

Now, we need a `ProcessElement` function that takes a `String` argument, does its thing, and returns a `String` - the problem is, you can't have a Boolean expression in a `Case` statement the way you have this `InStr` condition there, because the *data type* being resolved here is a `String`; in order for a `Case` block to be valid with a Boolean expression, we would need the `Select Case` argument to be a `Boolean` ...and we *can* actually do just that:

```
Private Function ProcessElement(ByVal element As String) As String
    Select Case True
        Case element = "UI"
            ProcessElement = "I am UI"

        Case element = "DB"
            ProcessElement = "I am DB"

        Case InStr(element, "API") > 0
            ProcessElement = "I am one of the API"

        Case Else
            ProcessElement = "I am nothing"

    End Select
End Function
```

Note: invoking `MsgBox` inside a loop is a very annoying idea. Consider using `Debug.Print` to output to the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G) instead.

Comment: I was using message boxes just as placeholders for example here. In my real code, I don't use message boxes. Also, I am iterating over array values which i forgot to specify in my problem statement, but thanks for clarifying it. I was able to use boolean the way you specified and it's working as expected now.

Comment: You could perhaps use `application.match` to avoid a loop.